# IIS - How do I know which folder IIS (v 7.5) will send logs to for a given website

Tags: iis, iis-7

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but looking at my IIS log files, I can deduce which folder contains logs for which site, because I am familiar with the sites.

However, I can't see anything that tells me that a particular site will send logs to (for example) W3SVC4.

In IIS 6, the log folder path is shown at the bottom of the logging properties UI, but not in IIS 7 as far as I can see.

If I had a lot of sites on the server, this could be harder to tell.

Is there a setting I can check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IIS manager open the feature pane for your site and double click on the Logging feature:

[image]

You'll get this dialogue:

[image]

The logging path is highlighted in the red box. The default path will be:

`%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVCxxxxxx`

Where `W3SVCxxxxxx` is created automatically based on the IIS number or ID of the site.

Comment: +1 / and you can find the site's ID "Advanced Settings" (in the "Actions" panel on the right in IIS Manager)

Comment: Thanks for the comment as it is this I'd that I'm interested in